# How to refactor my code to support new features of java 8 such as 'method references' for instance methods?

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8, android-studio-3.0

I have been using *Android Studio 3.0 Preview 1* to refactor my code.

I have enable Java-8 features for my code by following this link :

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html

I have refactored my code with lambdas by following 'Android Studio' suggestion.

Now, I am trying to use method reference where ever, the latest Android studio suggests.

How to call instance method that defined in the same class using method reference concept of java 8?

sample code :

```
Handler handler = getHandler();
handler.dowork(() -> refreshIt());// Need convert this line using  method references and refreshIt() is an instance method.
```

I am doing manually. Is there any way that Android studio(on Mac) refactor those method reference suggestions automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `this`:

```
handler.dowork(this::refreshIt);
```